# how to merge mulitple dataframes to one multiindex dataframe where each of merged dataframes becomes 2nd level column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, multi-index

What I'd like to achieve (without too much shuffling around) is to merge 3 different dataframes, each with same columns and indexes, but each representing different category.

df1

```
                                    Children    Movie enthusiast
household       
06f32e6e45da385834dac983256d59f3    0.086158    NaN
0d1974107c6731989c762e96def73568    0.120285    0.187764
0fd4f3b4adf43682f08e693a905b7432    0.400000    0.114686
11e0057cdc8b8e1b1cdabfa8a092ea5f    NaN         0.140000
120549af6977623bd01d77135a91a523    0.335238    0.192578
```

df2

```
                                    Children    Movie enthusiast
household       
06f32e6e45da385834dac983256d59f3    1.0         0.0
0d1974107c6731989c762e96def73568    4.0         11.0
0fd4f3b4adf43682f08e693a905b7432    1.0         5.0
11e0057cdc8b8e1b1cdabfa8a092ea5f    0.0         2.0
120549af6977623bd01d77135a91a523    7.0         9.0
```

df3

```
                                    Children    Movie enthusiast
household       
06f32e6e45da385834dac983256d59f3    nan         nan
0d1974107c6731989c762e96def73568    0.138       0.037
0fd4f3b4adf43682f08e693a905b7432    nan         0.025
11e0057cdc8b8e1b1cdabfa8a092ea5f    nan         0.153
120549af6977623bd01d77135a91a523    0.091       0.021
```

df_merged (filled by hand so not all values are present, but you get the idea)

```
                                    Children                Movie enthusiast
                                    df1      df2    df3     df1      df2    df3
household                       
06f32e6e45da385834dac983256d59f3    0.086158 1      NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN
0d1974107c6731989c762e96def73568    0.120285 4      0.138   0.187764 NaN    NaN
0fd4f3b4adf43682f08e693a905b7432    0.400000 1      NaN     0.114686 NaN    NaN
11e0057cdc8b8e1b1cdabfa8a092ea5f    NaN      0      NaN     0.140000 NaN    NaN
120549af6977623bd01d77135a91a523    0.335238 7      0.091   0.192578 NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with parameter `keys`, then [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) with [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) for desired format of `MultiIndex`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], keys=['df1','df2','df3'], axis=1)
       .swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)
       .sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)

                                  Children             Movie enthusiast  \
                                       df1  df2    df3              df1   
06f32e6e45da385834dac983256d59f3  0.086158  1.0    NaN              NaN   
0d1974107c6731989c762e96def73568  0.120285  4.0  0.138         0.187764   
0fd4f3b4adf43682f08e693a905b7432  0.400000  1.0    NaN         0.114686   
11e0057cdc8b8e1b1cdabfa8a092ea5f       NaN  0.0    NaN         0.140000   
120549af6977623bd01d77135a91a523  0.335238  7.0  0.091         0.192578   
household                              NaN  NaN    NaN              NaN   

                                        Movie enthusiastnthusiast  
                                    df3                       df2  
06f32e6e45da385834dac983256d59f3    NaN                      0.00  
0d1974107c6731989c762e96def73568  0.037                     11.00  
0fd4f3b4adf43682f08e693a905b7432  0.025                      5.00  
11e0057cdc8b8e1b1cdabfa8a092ea5f  0.153                      2.00  
120549af6977623bd01d77135a91a523  0.021                      9.01  
household                           NaN                       NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly! I didn't know swaplevel existed.